# Android Extended Button detect onClick

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, android-button

I have extended the Button class and not implemented `onClick` in extended button. And I am using the extended button every where and setting the `onClick` listener in each activity.

How can I detect the button is clicked in the Extended class.

```
public class ButtonExtended extends Button {
    public ButtonExtended(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ButtonExtended(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ButtonExtended(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public ButtonExtended(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }
    //onClick(){ here i want to detect the click }
}
```

In this `ButtonExtended` class, I want to detect, if the button is clicked just for the logging purpose. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `performClick()` behavior to get the clicked state.

```
public class ButtonExtended extends AppCompatButton{
public ButtonExtended(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public ButtonExtended(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
public ButtonExtended(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}
@Override
public boolean performClick() {
    Log.d("Button","performClick");
    return super.performClick();
}
}
```

`performClick()` will get called first before the the listener. Do not omit `return super.performClick()` in method `performClick()` this consume the event and your listener will not get called.